Major version publish is draft and not pending status?
I have existing libraries with content approval on which has worked in the past and I have this abnormal behaviour where if we complete major checking, the documents in the library are checked in but remain in draft status - and not "pending" as previously. We have not changed anything in our settings and this is odd behaviour. Any ideas what could be the issue?
